# ¿como puedo traer datos flitrados por una fecha mayor a la actual?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Intento con esto y cambio pero no se compara con la fecha actual, **¿Qué debo hacer?**

```
select e.name, e.id, e."year" 
from estates e 
where e."year" >= current_date();
```

Answer (score 0):

Bienvenido Diego, puede que tu error sea por el formato de fechas intenta con esto, lo que hago es darle el mismo formato de la fecha que tu guardas con la que vas a comparar (día -mes - año), también veo que en tu campo e.year puede que solo guardes solo el año o la fecha completa, para cualquiera de los dos casos te dejo un ejemplo funcional:

```
--Comparar por fecha completa
select e.name, e.id, e.year
from estates e 
where DATE_FORMAT(e.year, "%d %M %Y") > DATE_FORMAT(current_date(), "%d %M %Y");

--Comparar por año
select e.name, e.id, e.year
from estates e 
where DATE_FORMAT(e.year, "%Y") > DATE_FORMAT(current_date(), "%Y");
```

De igual forma te adjunto mi fuente de Mysql de donde eh obtenido bastantes combinaciones cuando se trata de fechas.

[Date and Time Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff)